# What's the most efficient brain–computer interface to play video games?

Tags: controllers, accessibility

I [read](https://jalopnik.com/neuralink-patient-shows-off-his-sick-mind-controlled-ma-1851363323):

> Technology for connecting paralyzed folks with computers has existed for a while now, according to [Bloomberg](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2024-03-20/musk-s-neuralink-gives-update-on-first-brain-implant-patient):
>
> > Neuralink is not the only company working on brain devices that connect with computers. Modern demonstrations of cursor control by using thoughts have taken place in other humans with various types of implants, such as those deployed by the BrainGate consortium of research institutions and hospitals.
> >
> > However, the Neuralink device contains more electrodes than other devices, suggesting it may have more potential applications in future. The Neuralink technology works without needing a wired connection to external devices.
> >
> > [...]
> >
> > “I’m happy for the individual that he’s been able to interface with a computer in a way he wasn’t able to before the implant,” said Kip Allan Ludwig, co-director of the Wisconsin Institute for Translational Neuroengineering. “That’s not a breakthrough compared to what others have shown previously, but it’s certainly a good starting point.”

This makes me wonder: What's the most efficient brain–computer interface to play video games? By most efficient, I mean allowing players to play the best.

---

To answer a comment on how to objectively compare BCI devices, see
e.g. the paper Satyam Kumar, Hussein Alawieh, Frigyes Samuel Racz, Rawan Fakhreddine, José del R Millán, Transfer learning promotes acquisition of individual BCI skills, PNAS Nexus, Volume 3, Issue 2, February 2024, pgae076, https://doi.org/10.1093/pnasnexus/pgae076 section "BCI control in a realistic scenario: car racing".

Comment: Hands.  Hands are the most popular brain controlled method for people to play games.  They integrate with a large number of popular peripherals such as keyboard/mouse, gamepads, joysticks, etc.  Most gamers (casual and professional) actually use hands, and few people complain about them.

Anyway, are you looking for a specific piece of equipment/periphery or a process?  Does it have to exist, or are you looking for something theoretical/emergent?

Comment: @DavidRobie Thanks, have to exist. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brain%E2%80%93computer_interface "A brain–computer interface (BCI), sometimes called a brain–machine interface (BMI) or smartbrain, is a direct communication pathway between the brain's electrical activity and an external device, most commonly a computer or robotic limb.", so natural limbs don't count, thanks!

Comment: Ah, so something which monitors brainwaves?  In that case, I guess you'd exclude external sensors such as eye and muscle trackers?

Comment: @DavidRobie yes, something which monitors brainwaves, such as Neuralink. I exclude external sensors such as eye and muscle trackers.

Comment: This is a heavily opinion-based Q as different users would perform differently using the same BCI and based on both general and specific game experience. Noland, the first Neuralink user, was playing Mario Kart and seemed to do great at it, but he had a lot of experience in the game (including while drunk) beforehand. It may be more effective to analyze the math and science, but then this would be better off on a Stack Exchange site for those as it wouldn't be about gaming.

Comment: @l3l_aze can have objective answers via user studies, measurements of key parameters such as latency, etc.

Comment: Many variables could differ based on environmental conditions, and with the environment starting inside a users brain and extending out into the surrounding world both in wired and wireless form there's plenty of room for results to get skewed in uncontrollable ways. Players playing their best is also effectively opinion-based whether it's their own opinion or someone else's.

Comment: @l3l_aze environmental conditions could be controlled pretty well I think. "Players playing their best is also effectively opinion-based whether it's their own opinion or someone else" we can find objective metrics, e.g. 1:1 game or measurable outcome such as time to complete a task.

Comment: Dependent on the person, but also on the game. Arguably every modern game requires a different approach to controls. While e.g. FPSs often have the same basic functions, nowadays game genres overlap so much that they can almost be told apart by their keymapping (think of Half-Life/Doom/Quake vs Dishonored/Deus Ex: Mankind Divided/CoDBlOps). And then there are wildly varying factors like speed, agility, timing, button-mashing, &c. (I'm not sure these all necessarily translate to BCI, but that brings up a new issue: many games have not been mapped to such interfaces anyway).

Comment: @Joachim I agree it may depend on the game and/or the factor you mention. The answer could discuss it.

Comment: The visually impaired community has an unfortunate history with companies designing brain interfaces for vision hardware that goes entirely unsupported after a handful of years.  A smartphone that goes EoL after a few years is a small problem compared to surgical implant with the life expectancy of a Great Dane.

Comment: @l3l_aze example of an objective answer: or Satyam Kumar, Hussein Alawieh, Frigyes Samuel Racz, Rawan Fakhreddine, José del R Millán, Transfer learning promotes acquisition of individual BCI skills, PNAS Nexus, Volume 3, Issue 2, February 2024, pgae076, https://doi.org/10.1093/pnasnexus/pgae076

Comment: I'm voting to leave this question closed. I don't think this fits within Arqade's area of expertise, even though it technically is video game-focused; [ux] would be a better fit IMO for asking about research-supported evaluation of BCI. And, I don't think the objective measure can be generalized from "perform specific task X" to "play games well", so I still think any answer (other than trivial answers like the existing one) would be opinionated.

Comment: @Schism Thanks for your feedback, one could decompose  "play games well" into its different input factors such as latency, control accuracy and number of different input types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am pretty certain there is currently no publicly available way to command a game without any physical interaction with your body (directly from brain to console).

There has been a few projects, but most are still in their infancy, or for neuralink are said to be far along, but to be frank, its promoted by Elon Musk that is starting to have a reputation of promising the moon and then not delivering anywhere close to what is promised.

So to wrap it up, currently you need to interface normally with your game, or at best with things like the [Xbox Accessibility Suite](https://www.xbox.com/en-US/community/for-everyone/accessibility)

Comment: There exist publicly available ways to command a game without any physical interaction with your body (directly from brain to console) eg Emotiv Epoc headset.  I had one over 10 years ago.